# thread-safety when returning a simple integer member variable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

In the following C# code snippet, is GetID() thread safe?

```
public class SharedData
{
    protected int _nID = 0;
    public int GetID()
    {
        return nID;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any replies!!

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by "thread safe". For example, if by "thread safe" you mean "all writes to this variable will be guaranteed to be observed on all threads as happening in a consistent order" then no, that's not at all "thread safe". If you mean "tests and sets of this variable are guaranteed to give results consistent with single-threaded data dependency rules" then no, that's not at all "thread safe".

Give us a careful definition of what "thread safe" means to you, and show us all the writers, and all the code that has data dependency on those readers and writers, and then we can give you a meaningful opinion.  There's not nearly enough information in this question to even begin to answer the question meaningfully.

Answer (score 2):

Reading is thread safe. If you are going to write to `nID`, then it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't modify anything. how can it be thread safe or not thread safe?

Comment: Sorry, assuming there's a thread-safe member function that can change its value.

Comment: @bl23: In that case you might want to mark `_nID` as `volatile` to ensure that any reading thread(s) don't cache stale values.

Comment: @bl23: Your assumption begs your own question. It's completely meaningless to say that a write is "thread safe" if one of the readers is not; thread safety is a property of the *entire system*, not of individual parts. Can you clearly define what "thread safe" means to you?